# How do I take in "A1"-style row+column specifications as input?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, input, ascii, tic-tac-toe

I am writing a TicTacToe game in C++. I am using a 2D character array to input each player's piece into a square. However, for input I am asking the user to type in A1, which will be board[0][0] and the top left corner of the game board. How do I allow the user to type in A1 but still allow that to be board[0][0] without hard coding? Also, the user can determine the board size. Min: 3x3, max: 13x16.

Comment: Will the board-size be configurable, or always the typical 3x3 of normal Tic-Tac-Toe? If not configurable, you might as well hard-code `'A'` to map to "column" (or "row") `0` and `'B'` to `1` etc. Then do the same mapping for the `'1'` in `"A1"`.

Comment: The user can define their board size. (Up to 13x16, min: 3x3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>(Assuming the board is 3x3, or at most 9x9)</sub>

Get two characters from the user, ensure the first is an uppercase letter and the second is a digit, and that they're in the right range.

Note that - on most platforms you are likely to be working on - if the character variable `c` has value `'A'`, `'B'` or `'C'` then the expression `c - 'A'` has value `0`, `1` or `2`, which you can use as an index. It's not 100% portable code, though, as @SomeProgrammerDude notes.

... if the board is larger you may have to allow for multiple-character specification of column and row, and parse them appropriately. The `c - 'A'` indexing will only work up to `'Z'` of course.

Comment: It should be noted that for letters this is only valid for encodings where the letters are consecutive (like ASCII). It will fail for e.g. EBCDIC.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Oh, I had assumed ASCII or Latin-1 or UTF-8 was somehow a valid assumption in the C++ standard. I stand corrected...